# How to delete non-needed rows while using read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file reads like this in .txt:

```
FullName: Ryan, Jack
DOB:12345
IDNUM: 1234455
Name,Age,City
jack,34,Sydeny,
Riti,31,Delhi,
Aadi,16,New York,
Suse,32,Lucknow,
Mark,33,Las vegas,
Suri,35,Patna,
```

Is there anyway to remove the first three rows of the csv file (FullName, DOB, and IDNUM) using read_csv()? I used header=3 and skiprows=3 and the resulting table is not what I am looking for and appears to be shifted off by one to the left. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried to solve this problem, and what specific issues are you encountering? Make sure to checkout [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the future.

Comment: Use ``skiprows`` instead

Comment: Even with skiprows the problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @xyzjayne, `skiprows` is the way to go.

```py
import pandas as pd
import io

myfile = """FullName: Ryan, Jack
DOB:12345
IDNUM: 1234455
Name,Age,City
jack,34,Sydeny,
Riti,31,Delhi,
Aadi,16,New York,
Suse,32,Lucknow,
Mark,33,Las vegas,
Suri,35,Patna,"""

fh = io.StringIO(myfile)
```

Let's read it using pandas' `read_csv()` method:

```py
df = pd.read_csv(fh,
                 skiprows=3,
                 usecols=range(3)
                )
```

NOTE: since your lines end with a comma, which would generate an extra column with `NaN` values, you also need `usecols` to return only a subset of the columns.

```py
>>> print(df)

   Name  Age       City
0  jack   34     Sydeny
1  Riti   31      Delhi
2  Aadi   16   New York
3  Suse   32    Lucknow
4  Mark   33  Las vegas
5  Suri   35      Patna
```